# How can I start Pry in Rails/Ruby automatically when any exception occurs, at the location of the raised exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception, pry

How can I start Pry in Rails/Ruby automatically when any exception occurs, at the location of the raised exception?

I have a hard to debug problem, that I can't seem to trace back to it's source, it occurs in Rails somewhere between a controller responding and a view being rendered.

I figured if I somehow got a pry (pry gem) to open up before or after the stack trace is displayed in the console I might be able to see where the issue has occurred. Is it possible to get Pry to start up automatically when an error occurs?

Or a debugger for that matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [pry-rescue](https://github.com/conradirwin/pry-rescue) it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) to set breakpoints and debug in the console using pry. Another thing you can try is to use [better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) which will give you a better error page and also an interactive console.